# Monodevelop.aspnet v5.7 missing

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

I recently took two actions and no longer have a stable Monodevelop environment.

1. Upgraded to 5.7 from the monodevelop repository
2. Installed Entity Framework via Nuget

As soon as I installed EF6, I started experiencing instability in my application. I decided to remove the package, and Monodevelop crashed. Upon reboot, I've lost the ability to open my ASP.Net project.

When I go to load my project, it has a yellow warning icon over and states:

```
The ASP.NET plug is not installed
```

When I go to addins, I get an error message stating that `MonoSoftDebugger for ASP.NET` cannot be installed because `MonoDevelop.Aspnet v5.7` is not available.

I did attempt to purge my whole mono setup and reinstall, but no differences. I have also tried loading other ASP.Net Projects, all are experiencing the same issue.

Extra Details

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

install method: apt-get install monodevelop
respository: deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
```

Comment: Are you able to try with older version of your application, like before removing Entity Framework? Are you able to start, compile and visit in browser new ASP.net project created via MonoDevelop?

Comment: Same thing is happening with me, can't create asp.net projects. I raised a bug on Bugzilla for this. Add yourself to the cc list https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26040

Comment: Is MD built from source or installed from http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/?

Comment: @Daniel Other ASP.net applications are also experiencing the problem.

Comment: @DavidKarlaš MD is installed via apt-get from mono-project.com. There was an update to that repository recently (as indicated by Shane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've pushed a *workaround* to this to the Debian repository (RPM will take another hour maybe).

The workaround should get the addin working with basic ASP.NEt and MVC1-3, but is missing support for MVC4 which is in the Windows/Mac Xamarin Studio. This was also the case with 5.5, so it shouldn't affect you in this instance.